# HTML column sorting in report generated by JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

Can we have column sorting in report which is generated (in *html* format) by *iReport* for example
if a report contains three column name, age, sex
and i want to sort report on clicking on age than it should sort based on age.

Comment: Why you not use table component?

Comment: @JitendraKumawat Are you talking about *JasperReports Server*?

Comment: If you are fetching data from mysql then you can make it by using query. if you are passing using list from java or grails then you need to sort your list by using java or grails.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't can use the table component (table component have this in native function), you can create a link this mode:

One idea is in your column header you create a link to the same report and send parameter with number of column in your SQL, after you can use this in your sql or procedure to sort.

Comment: But it will re-generate the report ?